# Resizing the layoutpanel in gwt

Tags: java, gwt

I am having difficulty resizing a table which is inside a container panelin gwt.
The table is not resizing on resizing the outer panel and thus I need a fix to this. 
I cannot post the code as the code is too long.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you not post only the relivant code?

Comment: Could you suggest a way to resize a layoutpanel when its outer panel gets resized? Actually my code is huge for this specific module and posting it online is not possible. If you could hint me a way of invoking the resize event or something that would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try something like:

```
setSize(Window.getClientWidth()*1/4+"px", Window.getClientHeight()*1/4+"px")
```

Comment: However would like to ask you a question Steve. Wouldn't this set the the browser window size and not the container panel size that is its height and width?Thank you so much. I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Yes, so you can change it like this `containerPanel.setSize(Window.getClientWidth()*1/4+"px", Window.getClientHeight()*1/4+"px")`

where `containerPanel` is the name of your panel. Also, you may want to change the 1/4 to other numbers depending on the size.

Comment: If you are trying to get the height of a panel as opposed to the main window, you can try this:
`myPanel.getElement().getClientHeight()` to get the height of the panel and then changing the size of the table. Your finished product should look like this:
`table.setSize(myWidget.getElement().getClientWidth()/4, myWidget.getElement().getClientHeight()/4)`